# SQL Query echo loop in 2 html table colums

Tags: php, html, css, pdf, dompdf

Is it possible to echo database data into 2 html table colums like a loop? I can't make it work. Or do I need a different approach?

I need this to echo like a loop into 2 columns `<?php echo $row['data']; ?>`

**This is what I have:**

```
HTML Table
Col 1    |    Col 2
1. aaaa
2. bbbb
3. cccc
4. dddd
5. eeee
6. ffff
7. gggg
8. hhhh
9. iiii
10. jjjj
```

**This is what I want:**

```
HTML Table
Col 1         |     Col 2
1. aaaa             6. ffff
2. bbbb             7. gggg
3. cccc             8. hhhh
4. dddd             9. iiii
5. eeee             10. jjjj
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13838755/php-while-loop-split-into-two

Comment: @Chocoprins  Nice scenario . . . I answered Your expected output let me check if you have any concern come back with comments . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here code is for creating dynamic column and data, that might any length,

Splitting into 5 groups and make it as column value. Worked output is below

```
<?php
 //$row=array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);
 $row=array('aaa','bbbb','cccc','ddddd','eeeee','ffff','gggg','hhhh','iiii','jjjjj','kkkk','llll','mmmm','nnnnn','ooooo');
?>
<table style="width:50%">
<?php
echo'<tr>';
$i=0;
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    if(($key)%5==0)
    {
        $i++;
        echo'<th>Col'.$i.'</th>';
    }
    $a[$i][]=$value;        
}
echo'</tr>';
$forcount=count($a);
$innerforcount=count($a[1]);
for ($j=0; $j <$innerforcount ; $j++) {
    echo'<tr>';
    for($i=1;$i<=$forcount;$i++)
        echo'<td>'.$a[$i][$j].'</td>';
    echo"</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

//Output

```
 Col1   Col2    Col3    Col4
1   6   11  16
2   7   12  17
3   8   13  18
4   9   14  19
5   10  15  20
```

//Sample out with text

```
 Col1   Col2    Col3
aaa     ffff    kkkk
bbbb    gggg    llll
cccc    hhhh    mmmm
ddddd   iiii    nnnnn
eeeee   jjjjj   ooooo
```

Comment: Rasa thank you very much but the array's are not actualy number but texts in 20 steps.

Comment: @Chocoprins18 Edited my answer check

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely possible.

All you need to do is `echo` out alternating classes, which can be done by making use of a counter which increments as you loop over the rows. For example:

```
<?php

$count = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
   $count++; // Increment a counter
   if ($count % 2 == 0 && $count != count($rows)) {
     echo "<div class='odd'></div>";
   }
   else {
     echo "<div class='even'></div>";
   }
}

?>
```

And from here you can use CSS to style the rows into two columns:

```
.odd, .even {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

Or if you want to do this with pure CSS, you can make use of flexbox. All you need is `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` on the parent, along with `flex: 50%` on the children:

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container div {
  flex: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Which will also allow you to fill the left-hand column first if you want, by making use of `flex-flow: column wrap` and a fixed `height`:

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column wrap;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understand your explanation 100%. I want to integrate this into DOMPDF so your entire example must be inside $html = 'YOUR EXAMPLE'; And it is here that it starts to get tricky in my way. So I don't know how to handle this and make it work.

Comment: DomPDF is basically a web parser; you simply add your entire HTML structure into it. And that includes the `<head>` tag, which in turn can include in-line CSS styling. You'd want something like `$html = "<html>
<head>
  <style>
  {{STYLES HERE}}
  </style>
</head> <body> ... </body>`. You'll probably want to save your entire 'body' as an independent (string) variable, and inject it as a part of the `$html` string: `$html = <html> ... </head><body>" . $body . "</body>";`.

Comment: Yes but your example does not work inside the $html

Comment: Hmm, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44764082/2341603), DomPDF does not support flexbox (or floats). You're likely stuck with `inline-block` elements. As I'm not familiar with DomPDF myself, I can't help much with the specific formatting you'll need sorry, but the concept is the same. I'll add the tag to the question.

Comment: Ok no problem. Can you tell me where I need to put the <?php echo $row['data']; ?> in your example. Im not 100% sure but the example is a counter so I don't have actually numbers but text in steps, so around 20 steps. The focus must be now on the table row instead of the counter if im right.